# Finding mean value of select items in a column in bash

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file that contains coordinates of atoms in the following format

```
A B C
1 2 1
some string
another line of string
  0.00  0.00  0.35
  0.33  0.99  0.37
  0.66  0.50  0.98
  0.66  0.00  0.38
```

A B and C are names of the different atoms in the system

The next line "1 2 1" gives the number of each type of atoms, so 1A, 2Bs and 1C.

The following lines with three columns of floats give the cartesian coordinates of each atom, so the first line is for A, second and third lines for each of the two Bs, the fourth line for C.

I want to find the average of the z coordinates of the two B atoms, i.e. Average(0.37, 0.98). and replace the z coordinate of atom C with that value, i.e. replace 0.38 with Average(0.37, 0.98).

In the actual problem I have, there are a few dozen files each with different numbers of A B and C atoms. so I need to read the numbers in row 2 and decide which rows of column 3 to operate on. Is there an efficient way to do this in bash, awk or something similar?

I know that I can read in the entire file and read the entire 3rd column into an array with something like the following and then operate.

```
#!/bin/bash

array_B=( $(cut -d ' ' -f3 file ) )
printf "%s\n" "${array_B[2]}"
```

But that has problems introduced by the first 4 lines and then the issue of identifying the relevant rows corresponding to B. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance
Jacek

---

Associated question:

If I want to change the z coordinate of atom A to the average of z coordinate of Atom Bs, how do I structure the code?
If we use AWK and let it read through the file line by line, the average is not computed until AWK reaches lines concerning atom B. For atom A which comes before Atom B, there will be a problem.
I think then we need to let AWK go over the file once to get the average, then another time to change the values of the third column for the rows concerned. However, I don't know how to set this variable. `awk -v` will only gives pre-defined value.

Comment: If you want to change the input files, don't.  Consider the files immutable.  If you need to modify the data, write the new data into a completely different directory tree. Disk is cheap.  Having redundant data on your filesystem temporarily is not a big deal.  Recovering from corrupt data is expensive; it will take time and cause great frustrtation.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I'm not overwriting the original file, just trying to edit the file according to what I described and save it as input for another calculation. However I can't figure out how to get awk to work as I described.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```sh
awk '
  BEGIN { start_b = end_b = 4; total = 0 } # Initial dummy values
  FNR == 2 { # Calculate line numbers for B and C atoms
             num_b=$2; start_b=4+$1; end_b=start_b+num_b
           }
  FNR <= start_b { print }
  FNR > start_b && FNR <= end_b { total += $3; print } # Sum up b z-coords
  FNR > end_b { printf "  %.2f  %.2f  %.2f\n", $1, $2, total / num_b } # Replace the C z-coords with average of b
  ' file
```

Comment: I have a question. If I want to change the z coordinate of A to the average of the z coordinates of the two B atoms, i.e. Average(0.37, 0.98), how should I structure the awk? Right now, because total is only updated when awk read to row containing B's information, when changing the z coordinate for A, total is still using the default value rather than the read value.